# Sliver Appbar "eliminates" the primary color

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I've a simple sliver app bar, and i set my primary color to this:

```
 theme: ThemeData(primary Color: Color. fromRGBO(50, 50, 205, 1)),
```

Before i added the sliver app bar all the screen was set to primary color,
But after i added the sliver app bar suddenly the screen turn to white.

**How do I set my primary color to fill the screen?**

it's a really simple sliver app bar, if you need the code for this let me know

Answer (score 0):

Still Don't know why this is happening, but i found a solution.

Just wrap your remaining screen with container and add color like this:

```
   SliverFillRemaining(
              child: Container(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(30, 30, 123, 1.0),
                child: ...your remaining screen
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use a Scaffold widget and inside it place the SliverAppBar and use the backgroundcolor property of Scaffold to set the color screen.